# What to keep in mind when creating your own custom web services API?

Tags: php, web-services, api

I have created a website which allows users to sign up for, and use, an online service. To help promote the website we will be have re-sellers who will be offering their own branded services through us. The initial plan is to allow re-sellers to place registration, login, and lost password forms on their own website and use an API created by us to handle these requests.

I have begun outlining how I expect the API to work (and starting documenting it as well) and I want to make sure I get it right, or as close to right, as I can from the beginning as I know once you have declared a public API you want to avoid changing that API at all costs.

So far I have decided:

- To have the user pass their account credentials with each request
- To require SSL for all requests

What else should I be keeping in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a presentation by Joshua Bloch that is a must read for API designers:

http://www.infoq.com/presentations/effective-api-design